# Calculate the run time analysis

Tags: algorithm

You can assume n to be the power of 2 for your analysis. I guess that its time complexity is theta(n^2).Please coorect me if I am wrong

```
i = 1
while i < n   
    i =2*i
```

Comment: Please remember that StackOverflow is for specific programming questions, not homework help.

Comment: I just need some advice. I will be more careful about it. Thanks for pointing it

Answer (score 2):

Complexity should be O(log(n)), certainly not n^2.

Consider that if n==8, the loop executes only 3 times (i=2, 4, 8)

O(n^2) would imply that the loop would execute 64 times - which is clearly wrong.